# PHP namespace removal / mapping and rewriting identifiers

Tags: php, namespaces, tokenize

I'm attempting to automate the removal of namespaces from a PHP class collection to make them PHP 5.2 compatible. (Shared hosting providers do not fancy rogue PHP 5.3 installations. No idea why. Also the code in question doesn't use any 5.3 feature additions, just that syntax. Autoconversion seems easier than doing it by hand or reimplementing the codebase.)

For rewriting the *.php scripts I'm basically running over a [tokenizer](http://php.net/token_get_all) list. The identifier searching+merging is already complete. But I'm a bit confused now how to accomplish the actual rewriting.

```
function rewrite($name, $namespace, $use) {

    global $identifiers2;            // list of known/existing classes

    /*
        bounty on missing code here
    */

    return strtr($name, "\\", "_");  // goal: backslash to underscore
}
```

That function is going to be invoked on each found identifier (whether class, function or const). It will receive some context information to transform a local identifier into an absolute/global $name:

```
$name =
    rewrite(
        "classfuncconst",      # <-- foreach ($names as $name)
        "current\name\space",
        array(
           'namespc' => 'use\this\namespc',
           'alias' => 'from\name\too',
           ...
        )
    );
```

At this stage I've already prepared an `$identifiers2` list. It contains a list of all known classes, functions and constant names (merged for simplicity here).

```
$identifiers2 = array(             // Alternative suggestions welcome.
   "name\space\Class" => "Class",  // - list structure usable for task?
   "other\ns\func1" => "func1",    // - local name aliases helpful?
   "blip\CONST" => "CONST",        // - (ignore case-insensitivity)
```

The `$name` parameter as received by the `rewrite()` function can be a **local**, **unqualified**, **\absolute** or **name\spaced** identifier (but just identifers, no expressions). The `$identifiers2` list is crucial to resolve *unqualified* identifiers, which can refer to things in the current namespace, or if not found there, global stuff.

And the various `use namespace` aliases have to be taken into account and add some complication besides the namespace resolving and precedence rules.

So, how / in which order would you attempt to convert the variations of class/function names here?

> #### Mental Laziness Bounty.
>
> To make this a less blatant plzsendtehcodez question: an explainative instruction list or pseudo-code answer would be eligible too. And if another approach would be more suitable for the task, please elaborate on that rather. (But no, upgrading PHP or changing the hoster is not an option.)
>
> I think I've figured it out meanwhile, but the question is still open for answers / implementation proposals. (Otherwise the bounty will obviously go to nikic.)

Comment: This converter could be extremely useful for a lot of people (including me). I would love to see the result!

Comment: Oh, and [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php) contains some information on namespace resolving.

Comment: I'm sure this convert will be reason of lot of bugs. And I think it's better to change hosting, than take such risky operations with code. Maybe it's for some library distribution, but even in this case, it will be better if this library will become a reason to install PHP 5.3.

Comment: @OZ_: There are no collisions if everything gets prefixed consistently (which is what this tool should do), so there might be a few special cases like dynamic function/method calls, but those can be avoided. You do not always have the choice to choose hosters. Some clients may want to use it on their own machine, etc. It is great to have such a tool for those cases.

Comment: how many files are going to be changes? Isn't it better to sacrifice several hours to make it done by hand? It'd cause less errors and problems in my opinion.

Comment: @Tomasz: In my case it's around 260 files, but there might be more dependencies (it's a PEAR2 class). Doing it by hand is pretty much unfeasible without knowing the codebase inside out. And it will be inescapable to introduce errors if done the tedious manual way (because that ensures things are getting overlooked). An automated replacement does reliably modify ***all*** identifiers. And except if the codebase has a reliance on `eval`ed identifiers in strings, I can't imagine why it should cause problems. (It might need some manual editing still.)

Comment: If it is such sensitive code, I would look for another host if I were you.

Comment: **Getting it to run on php 5.2 is the question topic and constraint.**

Comment: @mario, so give rep bounty for this question at least. Frankly, it's big work.

Comment: @OZ_: Yep, going to. Could probably figure this out myself, but too lazy; and that's what bounties are for after all. (Just need to improve the question details a bit more..)

Comment: @mario: you are the [first answerer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers) of the PHP tag. If you don't have a solution you will not get one here lol. 320 points is awesome

Comment: @yes123: Oh. Just goes to show that I had too few other things to do this month. -- But there's probably someone who can answer it..

Comment: @mario: Are you going to publish your results?

Comment: @nikic: Too lazy, not finished. But going to add it here.

Answer (score 18):

In an [existing question on migration of namespaces to pseudo namespaced code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836387/strategy-for-developing-namespaced-and-non-namespaced-versions-of-same-php-code) I already [introduced a conversion tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836387/strategy-for-developing-namespaced-and-non-namespaced-versions-of-same-php-code/3661724#3661724) I have written as part of a larger project. I haven't maintained this project anymore since that point, but as far as I remember the namespace replacements did work. (I may reimplement this project using a [proper parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) at some point. Working with plain tokens has proven to be quite a tedious task.)

You will find my implementation of namespace -> pseudo-namespace resolution in the [namespace.php](https://github.com/nikic/prephp/blob/master/prephp/listeners/namespaces.php#L203). I based the implementation on the [namespace resolution rules](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php), which will probably be of help for you, too.

To make this a less blatant readmycodez answer, here the basic steps the code does:

1. Get the identifier to be resolved and ensure that it is not a class, interface, function or constant declaration (these are resolved in [registerClass](https://github.com/nikic/prephp/blob/master/prephp/listeners/namespaces.php#L170) and [registerOther](https://github.com/nikic/prephp/blob/master/prephp/listeners/namespaces.php#L185) by simply prepending the current namespace with ns separators replaced by underscores).
2. Determine what type of identifier it is: A class, a function or a constant. (As these need different resolution.)
3. Make sure we do not resolve the `self` and `parent` classes, nor the `true`, `false` and `null` constants.
4. Resolve aliases (`use` list):

   1. If the identifier is qualified get the part before the first namespace separator and check whether there exists an alias with that name. If it does, replace the first part with the aliased namespace (now the identifier will be fully qualified). Otherwise prepend the current namespace.
   2. If identifier is unqualified and the identifier type is `class`, check whether the identifier is an alias and if it is, replace it with the aliased class.
5. If the identifier is fully qualified now drop the leading namespace separator and replace all other namespace separators with underscores and end this algorithm.
6. Otherwise:

   1. If we are in the global namespace no further resolution required, thus end this algorithm.
   2. If the identifier type is `class` prepend the current namespace, replace all NS separators with underscores and end this algorithm.
   3. Otherwise:

      1. If the function / constant is defined globally leave the identifier as is and end this algorithm. (This assumes that no global functions are redefined in a namespace! In my code I don't make this assumption, thus I insert dynamic resolution code.)
      2. Otherwise prepend the current namespace and replace all namespace separators with underscores. (Seems like I got a fault in my code here: I don't do this even if the `assumeGlobal` flag is set. Instead I always insert the dynamic dispatch code.)

Additional note: Don't forget that one can also write `namespace\some\ns`. I resolve these constructs in [the `NS` function](https://github.com/nikic/prephp/blob/master/prephp/listeners/namespaces.php#L32) (which is also responsible for finding namespace declarations).

Comment: Pretty interesting. Looks like this is almost a solved task then. Since your implementation is significantly cleaner, I'd use that if I can't get mine to work. And you've already solved the lambda function issue among others. (Working on a token list does really just complicate the matter, but at least it's workable with some concessions.) -- The global function/class ambiguity might be an issue, which is also why I tried that $identifiers2 list workaround.

Comment: @mario: I added a description of what the resolve function does in case that you want to implement your own version (and that's probably not unreasonable, as my code was more meant to be used for general conversion of 5.3 -> 5.2 and not porting specific projects. In the latter case you can incorporate your own knowledge of the project to make the conversion more nice).

Comment: Solved the namespace\ prefix with an implicit alias `$use["namespace"] = $namespace;`, and some other gotchas you mentioned (parent, self) by accident. While I have separated the class, func, const declarations, I don't really differentiate them by context in the token stream (for simplicity). But I thought it makes not enough difference if I knew declared identifiers. - I'm not sure about your first point: don't you rewrite the name declarations finally too? (I'm going to read through the listeners code more thoroughly..)

Comment: @mario: I rephrased my first point. The declarations are rewritten separately, not in this function, by simply prepending the current namespace (and replace the underscores). That's what I meant with this point ;)