# making php 5.1 ignore namespace

Tags: php, frameworks, namespaces, composer-php

I made a small framework for my site using php 5.6. Unfortunately, I noticed just before uploading to the Hosting plateform that its web server has php 5.1.3. The minimum version for my website must be php 5.3 because of the use of namespaces (and composer).

Can I make php 5.1 ignore the namespaces or do I have to rewrite the scripts?

Comment: 5.1!!!! holy cow, get the hell away from them :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP namespace removal / mapping and rewriting identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104321/php-namespace-removal-mapping-and-rewriting-identifiers)

Comment: No PHP versions before 5.4 are currently maintained. This means no security updates for 5.3 and below. I agree with @FélixGagnon-Grenier. Find a new hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make versions < 5.3 of PHP ignore namespaces.

To help you migrate (or automate the migration) your code, check that : [PHP namespace removal / mapping and rewriting identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104321/php-namespace-removal-mapping-and-rewriting-identifiers)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm sorry it seems like a duplicate but i didn't find the question you pointed me to.

Comment: There's a composer package witch creates an autoloader for php versions before 5.3. You  can get it at: https://bitbucket.org/xrstf/composer-php52.

Comment: The link is dead. 
Now that the provider finally  switched to php 5.6, I don’t need this anymore and that’s great.